# training a network to do detection task

Tags: object-detection, detection, training-data

I have approximately 100,000 images for doing detection task.
In average there are 10 target objects in each individual image. However, all the objects are not labeled. for example from 10 objects, 5 of them have boxes and others does not have any boxes. Do you think training the network with this data would be a good idea? or is it required to all the objects in the image have bounding boxes?

Comment: try it with [red freehand-circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138031/is-there-a-joke-about-freehand-circles-that-im-oblivious-to) around the targets since they allow more organic shapes than just a square box ;)

Comment: Some fast detection algorithms use cascading networks where first networks detect anything remotely similar with deeper ones filtering out erroneous detections. You can train a few layers of a cascade on your data adding the number of detections above average to the error, but you will  need complete data for later. Alternatively if you can select regions definitely not containing target objects (maybe they never appear close to each other?), you can use your data well. The only problem is if unmarked objects are viewed as erroneous detection and that is how you can get rid of it.

Comment: If you are trying to detect all 10 objects and only 5 of them are labeled, it will result in a problem, especially if you need to predict bounding box, there is an option of using Naive sliding window implementation and segmenting labeled Images, but that will have a massive effect on your speed.